# Get line and line number from Select-String

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, select-string

I have this script which works great, but I would also need it to return the line number and the line.

If I do

```
Select-String w:\test\york\*.* -pattern "mistake"
```

I get

```
W:\test\york\test.html:179:<p>If you notice a mistake on an information slip, contact the employer, payer, or administrator for that slip.</p>
W:\test\york\test.html:180:<p>If you notice a mistake in the tax-related information or have an account-specific question about other tax-related information, call the Individual income tax and trust enquiries line at 1-800-959-8281.</p>
```

Which is perfect. However, in my script, which is this:

```
param(
    [string]$pattern,
    [string]$path  
) 
$exclude = '*\test\*'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html | Where-Object {
    ForEach-Object {
        if (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "<h2>Stay Connected") {
            Select-String -InputObject (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -Pattern "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)<h2>Stay Connected"
        } elseif (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "<h2>Soyez branch") {
            Select-String -InputObject (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -Pattern "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)<h2>Soyez branch"
        } else {
            Select-String -InputObject (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) -Pattern "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)<\/main>"
        }
    }
} | Select Fullname | ? {$_.FullName -notlike $exclude}
```

I only get this as a result in my CSV:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.IO.FileInfo
FullName
W:\test\york\test.html
```

How can I get the results of the simple search, in my CSV file, using the script?

---

Edited as per Ansgar Wiechers' answer.

`$pattern` is "textbook".

This is my current code:

```
param(
    [string]$pattern,
    [string]$path,
    [string]$name  
) 
$expr = "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)" +
        '(?:<h2>Stay Connected|<h2>Soyez branch|<\/main>)'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html |
    Select-String -Pattern $expr |
    Select-Object Path, LineNumber, Line |
    Export-Csv "W:\test\search_results\$name.csv" -NoType
```

If I replace

```
$expr = "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)" +
        '(?:<h2>Stay Connected|<h2>Soyez branch|<\/main>)'
```

by

```
$expr = $pattern
```

I get 6 results (which is correct), but if I use the provided expression by Ansgar, I get no results. What am I missing to get the expression to work properly?

Comment: Wow, that's.... Tip: There's nothing wrong with variables (to store file content) and a `foreach ($file in $files)`. You don't have to use the pipeline. The most important part when learning a new language is readability. :-)

Comment: Do you get a matches if you use just `"(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)"`? Can you provide sample input?

Comment: I get no matches if I just use that. I also tried to use Select-String -Pattern "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)" | without any results. If I try the regex is sublime text, it does find them. Is it perhaps not seeing it as a regex search?

Comment: Would it cause a problem if that regex is a multi-line result?

Comment: Yes. Or rather, the problem is caused by `Select-String` reading each file as an array of lines instead of a single string. See updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

```
$expr = "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)" +
        '(?:<h2>Stay Connected|<h2>Soyez branch|<\/main>)'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html
foreach ($filename in $files) {
    Get-Content $filename -Raw |
        Select-String -Pattern $expr } |
        Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$filename}}, LineNumber, Line |
        Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
}
```

There's no need to check each file twice. Or use different expressions. Simply loop over the output of `Get-ChildItem`, pipe each file's content into `Select-String` and select the relevant properties of the resulting `MatchInfo` objects.

In principle `Select-String` could even read the files by itself. However, it would process the content as an array of lines, thus preventing multiline matches. Because of that you have to read the file with `Get-Content -Raw` (or `Get-Content | Out-String` in PowerShell v2 and earlier) to get the content in one string.

If you need to filter out paths containing a folder `test` you should do it right after the `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html |
         Where-Object { $_.FullName -notlike $exclude }
foreach ($filename in $files) {
    Get-Content ...
}
```

Technically it's possible to do it after the `Select-String` as well:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html
foreach ($filename in $files) {
    ...
        Where-Object { $_.Path -notlike $exclude } |
        Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType
}
```

However, filtering output after processing is a waste of resources when you could just as well filter the input and avoid generating results you don't want in the first place.

Comment: ok, if I go with your code, I am not getting the expression to work. it always return empty files, but if I just put the $pattern variable I get something.

param(
    [string]$pattern,
    [string]$path,
    [string]$name  
) 
$expr = "(?sm)<main([\w\W]*)$pattern([\w\W]*)" +
        '(?:<h2>Stay Connected|<h2>Soyez branch|<\/main>)'
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Filter *.html |
    Select-String -Pattern $expr |
    Select-Object Path, LineNumber, Line |
    Export-Csv "W:\test\search_results\$name.csv" -NoType

Comment: The code I posted is a snippet that fixes the problem described in your question. It's not a ready-to-run script and not intended to be one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a complete newbie at powershell, and I'm under pressure to come up with a solution using powershell. How can I get your solution to run? If I replace your code with just the variable, it works, but I need the regex search. How can I get it working? Thanks for everything!

Comment: What do you mean by "replace your code with just the variable"? Please edit your question, show the code you currently have and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: This does not work, because the moment you write `Get-Content -Raw`, select string only sees one line, so `LineNumber` is always 1.